# How is the P function applied in QSVT for the case of Hamiltonian simulation if it only modifies singular values?

Tags: circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation, hamiltonian

I am watching Andras Gilyen's talk on QSVT [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DGNgayZPj8&t=41s).

On one slide he mentions the core of QSVT:

[image]

Given $U$--- a block encoding of matrix $A$ that has singular values $\lambda$, left singular vectors, $\left | w \right >$, and right singular vectors $\left < v \right |$

$
U = \begin{bmatrix} A & . \\ . & . \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_i \lambda_i \left | w_i \right > \left < v_i \right | & . \\ . & . \end{bmatrix}
$

We can construct $V_\vec{\phi}$ that is:

$
V = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_i P(\lambda_i) \left | w_i \right > \left < v_i \right | & . \\ . & . \end{bmatrix}
$

However, on a following slide regarding Hamiltonian simulation, he brings this up:

[image]

What is $P(H)$ here? I thought $P$ could only act on singular values (and that is supported by $P$ having a domain of just $[-1, 1]$). Is this $P(H)$ correct? If so, is there another definition behind it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $P(A)$ is defined as acting in the singular basis of $A$, i.e.
$$
\begin{align}
P(A) = \sum_i P(\sigma_i) |w_i\rangle\langle v_i| = W P(\Sigma) V^\dagger.
\end{align}
$$
For Hermitian matrices, this just follows from the spectral decomposition of $A$.  More generally, if $A$ is at least diagonalizable then $P$ will act over the eigenvalues of $A$ in the same way.  Most generally, as the authors consider, *any* matrix has an SVD $A = W \Sigma V^\dagger$, in which case we can get $P$ to act as expected over the singular values (always real) if we make sure to alternate between $U$ and $U^\dagger$ (so that $W$ and $V$ are always hit by $W^\dagger$ and $V^\dagger$, respectively).